# boto3.client.list_objects_v2 not displaying recent files, Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to list recently uploaded files from AWS S3 Bucket

But below code does not show top files

```
S3_Access_Key, S3_Secret_Key, S3_Region_Name, S3_Bucket, S3_Key = Bucket_Credentials(Bucket) # My Function to get Credentials

S3_Client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=S3_Access_Key, aws_secret_access_key=S3_Secret_Key, region_name=S3_Region_Name)

Response = S3_Client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=S3_Bucket, Prefix=S3_Key)
Response = pd.DataFrame(Response['Contents'])
S3_Contents = Response[['Key', 'LastModified', 'Size']]

S3_Contents['Files'] = [s.split('/')[-1] for s in S3_Contents['Key']]

S3_Contents = S3_Contents.sort_values(['LastModified'], ascending=[False])
print(S3_Contents[['Files', 'LastModified', 'Size']].head(10))
```

Bucket Top Files:
[image: S3 Bucket, Marked in Red not displaying]

Shows below items only:

```
0  25f1a8d1-3f35-4c87-9b1a-64687ab48d4d.gz 2019-10-25 13:38:13+00:00   57071951
1  598dee47-1d57-4807-88a4-f29e27a82505.gz 2019-10-24 15:41:36+00:00   57713744
2  9c41617a-c7cd-4beb-98bb-7e49812dcac9.gz 2019-10-24 15:41:13+00:00   64267610
3          COMSTATCSITC2019_24Oct19.csv.gz 2019-10-24 11:19:40+00:00  136841622
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Code Works:

```
S3_Access_Key, S3_Secret_Key, S3_Region_Name, S3_Bucket, S3_Key = Bucket_Credentials(Bucket)
S3_Resource = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=S3_Access_Key, aws_secret_access_key=S3_Secret_Key, region_name=S3_Region_Name)
S3_Resource_Bucket = S3_Resource.Bucket(S3_Bucket)
S3_RS_Bucket_Objects = S3_Resource_Bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=S3_Key)

All_Files = []
for Object in S3_RS_Bucket_Objects:
   All_Files.append(Object.key)

Files_Uploaded = [s.split('\\')[-1] for s in Files_to_Upload]   
All_Files = [s.split('/')[-1] for s in All_Files]
Not_Uploaded = [Item for Item in Files_Uploaded if Item not in All_Files]
if len(Not_Uploaded) == 0:
    print('>> Success')
else:
    print('>> Failed: Some files not uploaded, Please cross check:\n', ', '.join(Not_Uploaded))
```

Comment: You should explain what the problem was in the original code and how this fixes it. That will help future readers with a similar issue so that they don't have to decipher the solution by reading the code.

Comment: @jarmod, OK Sorry

Answer (score 1):

**AWS CLI**

Here's an [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) command to list the 10 most-recently modified objects in an Amazon S3 bucket:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --prefix foo/ --query 'reverse(sort_by(Contents, &LastModified))[0:10].[Key]' --output text
```

**boto3**

This script sorts objects in reverse order of `LastModified`, then prints the first 10.

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket', Prefix='foo/')

sorted_contents = sorted(response['Contents'], key=lambda object: object['LastModified'], reverse=True)

for object in sorted_contents[:10]:
    print(object['Key'].split('/')[-1], object['LastModified'], object['Size'])
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, But still same results.

 25f1a8d1-3f35-4c87-9b1a-64687ab48d4d.gz 2019-10-25 13:38:13+00:00 57071951
 598dee47-1d57-4807-88a4-f29e27a82505.gz 2019-10-24 15:41:36+00:00 57713744
 9c41617a-c7cd-4beb-98bb-7e49812dcac9.gz 2019-10-24 15:41:13+00:00 64267610
 COMSTATCSITC2019_24Oct19.csv.gz 2019-10-24 11:19:40+00:00 136841622
 4f6d77d1-fbd1-4198-b06e-80ac236378d9.gz 2019-10-18 06:15:41+00:00 55579710

Comment: I have marked some top items of my bucket in attached image in question, its uploaded by boto3.client.upload-file, those items not displaying

Comment: Is it due to the `Prefix`? If you remove the `Prefix` parameter, it will work for _all_ objects in the bucket.

Comment: I have tried using "boto3.resource" its working, but it loads all files.